# Physical significance of Dirac equation in (2+1)D

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

What's is the physical significance of the two inequivalently irreducible-represented Dirac equations in (2+1)D? As it is known, all the $4\times 4$ matrix representations of the Dirac algebra $\gamma^{\mu}$ is equivalent in (3+1)D. For the massless case, the Dirac equation splits to two independent equations with respect to chirality. In (2+1)D, we may have two inequivalent representations, say, $\{\gamma^0 = \sigma^z,\gamma^1 =i\sigma^x,\gamma^2=i\sigma^y\}$ and $\{\gamma^0 = \sigma^z,\gamma^1 =-i\sigma^x,\gamma^2=i\sigma^y\}$. Therefore, we can have two different versions of Dirac equation, with or without mass$$(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} -m)\phi =0.$$ Under the parity transformation, they may be related to each other with a sign difference in the mass term. So does it mean that these two different representations are for positive and negative energy particles , respectively?

Comment: Consider clarifying this post by including the equation and the context in which you found it

Answer (score 1):

In odd space-time dimensions, a Dirac mass term violates parity symmetry. In 2+1 dimensions, and if the   the particles have charge $e$, an electric field will produce a ``parity anomaly'' vacuum current that is at right-anges to the applied ${\bf E}$ field, and whose direction (right or left) depends on the sign of $m$.  If you change the set of gamma matrices to their inequivalent set, while keeping ${\bf E}$ and $m$ fixed, the right and left directions interchange. So the inequivalent representations correspond to different physics.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, both fields are related with a parity transformation, but also each one of the fields has their respective conjugate field $\bar{\phi}$. When we get the electrodynamic coupling we can see that these fields $\bar{\phi}$ correspond to particles with opposite charge. In 2+1 almost all discrete transformations takes one representation to the other such as parity and temporal inversion.

Nevertheless, there is a link between these 2+1 fields of different representations and the chiral fields for the 3+1 Dirac field. If we take 3+1 Dirac equation and cancel the $z$-derivative terms we can get equations for the left and right chiral fields. These equations result nothing else but the equations for 2+1 Dirac fields. Then, we can interpretate that lowing the dimension results in some extra features for chiral fields $\chi_L$ and $\chi_R$. We can also write coupled chiral equations trough defining new fields with the fields of both representations.

It's usual not to work with both representations in different equations, but to work with a reducible representation which contains the two representations:
\begin{equation}
\gamma^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma^\mu_A & 0 \\
0 & \gamma^\mu_B
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
This way we get to work with one bispinor field $\psi$ composed by the two fields. Then the respective conjugate field $\bar{\psi}$ corresponds to a particle with opposite charge.